# How To Locate Header Files in GNUstep In Windows XP

Tags: header-files, gnustep

I am completely new to objective c. I am trying to compile a very basic program of "hello world", but the problem is that gcc compiler can't figure out where my header files are. I wrote on cygwin bash shell:

```
$ gcc -lobjc hello.m -o hello
```

and error given was:

```
hello.m:9:25: fatal error: foundation.h no such file or directory
```

I am using GNUstep on windows xp, having installed all the components needed. I know and have seen that header files are present. Please someone can guide me how can I locate those files? Or how should i give command to locate files myself? Is there any other possible way that I can permanently tell that in this folder header files are located.

And also please can someone point out to a good link from where I can learn objective c. Actually I am preparing myself to built an iPhone app and needs to do practice on windows for some weeks due to some reasons....

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out problem and figured out solution for this. Actually I had installed **GNUstep sys** with **cygwin** thats why compiler could not figured out the correct directory. My installation was incorrect. So I uninstalled all and reinstalled:

- GNUstep core 0.29.0
- GNUstep msys 0.29.0
- GNUstep devel 1.4.0

and now everything is going fine.

More help on installation can be get from [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Windows)