# Is it possible to write IOS code in windows notepad and then run it on iphone without mac machine

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, windows

I am new in IOS, is it possible that I want to write source code in notepad/notepad++ for iphone apps and want to then run it on apple iphone device without mac machine through command prompt or any free tools? If it is possible then suggest how to write files with extension and collect it in a particular folder then how to run it?

I already searched regarding this but not find proper answer for it, please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can *write* any code in Notepad, but you will need Mac OS and XCode to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compile and run simple `Objective C` using Notepad and [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html). You can't test and develop code for iOS without having mac and xcode. If you just want to use objective C, follow tutorial [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Windows). Also you can check out steps to be followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421620/how-to-locate-header-files-in-gnustep-in-windows-xp).